# SSH: How to avoid the security issues stemming from a ssh connection run by root

Tags: ssh, security

I need to push MySQL database backups from `server A` (production database) to `server B` (backup server), using rsync (and thus: ssh).

It would be very practical (permissions-wise) for me to be able to do this by running a ssh connection as root (root user on `server A`), initiated by a root cron job. However, I have read that one should generally do as little as possible with root, for security reasons.

So my question is: How do I avoid the security issues stemming from a ssh connection run by root? (Or are my security worries overblown?)

Comment: Why can't the database user run the backup? It should already have the necessary permissions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Well, the ssh connection uses a passphrase-protected key. Thus, the passphrase must be stored somewhere (before it's then given to the ssh-agent). My take is: passwords/passphrases should never be stored anywhere else than under root. The database user would thus not be able to read it.

Comment: So either remove the passphrase or use a different key.